# How to concurrently work on two git/gerrit branches?

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I have a situation where I need to create my branch(Say BranchB) out of a different branch(say BranchA) that is not merged yet. BranchA is up for gerrit review and modification goes on everytime in that branch.

If I go to gerrit UI, I am able to see the download dropdown on topmost righthand corner. Clicking which gives me an option to checkout. The command is something like,

```
git fetch ssh://**@**gerrit..****:12345/project-repo refs/changes/02/89765/15 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Using this I created my own local branch i.e BranchB and I also have the code from BranchA. Now the other person who works on BranchA, posted some updates which is necessary for me as well and I wanted to do `git pull --rebase`. But it didn't work. It asks me to specify the branch I want to pull. I tried doing a `git fetch --all` to update all remote branches in my local and tried to do `git pull --rebase` again. Didn't work either. 
What is the solution and the ideal way to create branches in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

While changes aren't merged they are in special (magical) branches like "refs/changes/02/89765/15" which are not fetched by regular "git fetch" command. But you can fetch and rebase it with the following commands:

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/02/89765/15
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
```

The "15" at the end shows that this is the patchset 15 of the change.

Comment: It gave me an error while executing first fetch itself git fetch refs/changes/02/124902/20

Error is:-
fatal: 'refs/changes/02/124902/20' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Sorry, the "origin" was missing... I fixed the answer.